# How to submit dynamic data without form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, forms, javabeans

I am getting data as form of Java Bean and I am inserting each value into a table.
Values are retrieved as common way at first. 
But I added some Javascript source, so that I can modify the value if I click any area near it.
Now I would like to save the data in database as well if there was any change after I modify.
How can I do that?

Here is my HTML code

```
<table class="bg-light table table-hover" style="overflow:hidden">
    <th>Word</th>
    <th>Dialogue</th>
    <th>Practice</th>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="engboardVO">
    <tr>
        <td data-editable>${engboardVO.word}</td>
        <td data-editable>${engboardVO.dialogue}</td>
        <td data-editable>${engboardVO.practice}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

And Javascript

```
$("body").on("click", "[data-editable]", function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    /*  var $input = $('<input style="width:500px; height:100px"/>').val( $el.text() ); */
    var $input = $('<textarea rows=5 style="width:500px"/>').val($el.text());
    $el.replaceWith($input);
    var save = function() {
        var $td = $("<td data-editable />").text($input.val());
        $input.replaceWith($td);
    };
    $($input).blur(function() {
        save();
    })
});
```

Comment: You want to save the edited value in database or only on table? Cannot understand your question.

Comment: @KiranShahi Database

Comment: do you have services or api to updated that?

Comment: If you mean update query in database, not yet. I can do that easily if it was only one form, but since the HTML table contains 10 rows per page, I don't know how to....

Comment: You need to make api and update each item on every save through ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax for submitting data without form.
I can see you are using jQuery library. So I am writing code based on this library.

In HTML:

```
<table class="bg-light table table-hover" style="overflow:hidden">
    <th>Word</th>
    <th>Dialogue</th>
    <th>Practice</th>
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="engboardVO">
    <tr>
        <td data-name="word" data-editable>${engboardVO.word}</td>
        <td data-name="dialogue" data-editable>${engboardVO.dialogue}</td>
        <td data-name="practice" data-editable>${engboardVO.practice}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

In javascript:

```
    $("body").on("click", "[data-editable]", function() {
    var $el = $(this);

    var $input = $('<textarea rows=5 style="width:500px"/>').val($el.text());
    $el.html($input);
    var field_name = $el.attr('data-name');
    var save = function() {
        var $val= $input.val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update-url",
            data: {fieldname: field_name, fieldvalue:$input.val()},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
               // do something on success
                $el.html($val);
            },
            error: function(msg){
              // do something on error
            }
        });
    };
    $($input).blur(function() {
        save();
    })
    });
```

Then in server side, you can save fieldvalue as value of fieldname in your database.

Basically what we are doing here is:

1. Added an attribute data-name in td tag, its value can be related to your field name in table.
2. Get the name of attribute in javascript using var field_name = $el.attr('data-name');.
3. Using post request in ajax call passed the field_name and and value of this field to server.

   ```
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "update-url",
           data: {fieldname: field_name, fieldvalue:$input.val()},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(msg) {
              // do something on success
               $el.html($val);
           },
           error: function(msg){
             // do something on error
           }
       });
   ```
4. Now in server side, you need to fetch this data as you fetch normally for post request in submit of a form and save this data in database.
5. url is same as action you provide in form tag.

**Edit:**
Check now. You were replacing the td, whereas you had to replace html inside td.

Comment: Because of `td data-editable` code after cell loses focus, every cell lose the value of their data-name. And that makes the second and after try end up with nothing changed.

Comment: @KimHyungJune,  Edited answer:  $el.relacewith($input); change to $el.html($input);

Comment: Thanks, but every time I click any editable cell and lose controll, text inside disappears.

Comment: @KimHyungJune, check now. You were replacing the td, whereas you had to replace html inside td.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry if you don't have a form or can't have it for some reasons

You can still read the inputs of your web page and use them or send them to the server.

See below a simple example:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var data = []
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
    // deal with inputs[index] element.
    data.push(inputs[index].value)
}

var json = JSON2.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your-api-url",
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        // done code
    }
});
```

Comment: Can I also read the data in <TD> tag if I follow your suggestion?